# loadView EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a button that pushes another viewcontroller onto my navigationcontroller. When I press the button, I will get EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the line where I add the subview statusLabel.
When I remove that line. I can compile and run, I can also go to my other view.

```
- (void)loadView
{
    statusLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 0.0, 150.0, 43.0)] autorelease];
    [self.view addSubview:statusLabel];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Debug your code properly at click event. You may have not allocated the object.

Comment: Some more information concerning code would be appreciated.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `self.view` to get the view inside loadView.  The purpose of loadView is the create the main view when you don't use a nib.  The `self.view` getter calls loadView when the view is not yet loaded and would be recursive.

Comment: This is not Xcode-specific. Tags edited.

Comment: Hmm but I have seen alot of people doing it this way :S

Comment: I fixed it, I just had to alloc self.view with a frame :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`loadView` method is used for custom view loading (i.e. creating `self.view` and adding all of its subviews). If you have your controller's view in a nib you should place this code into `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: I'm doing it without a nib file :O Want to do it programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I'm a few years late to the party but just ran into this myself.. In my case (which looks to be the same as your case) be sure to call `super.loadView()`